# PHP Extracting Operators and the values from String

Tags: php

in my code i need to get both operator and the values to do my calculation. my code is,

> $demension = "3.5x2.3=>4.8x8.9"

```
    public function searchItems($dimension)
    {
    $out= preg_split('/[x-]/', $dimension);
    $i=0;
    foreach ($out as $key) {
        preg_match('/(!=|=|<=|<|>=|>)/',$key,$matches);
        if(!empty($matches))
        {
            $result[$i]=$matches;
        }else
        {
            $result[$i]=$key;
        }

        $i++;
    }


    return $result;
```

}

I need to get 3.5,2.3,=>,4.8,8.9 separately
can any one show me the right path.

Comment: What are the operators and the values in $demension? (By the way, it's spelled dimension)

Comment: $dimension = "3.5x2.3=>4.8x8.9"

Comment: yes, I can read that. But what part are the operators, and what part are the values in that string???

Comment: operator "=>"     values 3.5,2.3,4.8,8.9

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here it is. Using a regexp to get values and operators.

```
function getParts($string)
{
    $regexp = "/(\d+?\.\d+?)|([<>=]+)/";

    $parts = [];

    if (preg_match_all($regexp, $string, $matches)) {
        $parts = $matches[0];
    }

    return $parts;
}

$dimension = "3.5x2.3=>4.8x8.9"
print_r(getParts($dimension));
```

Comment: you can add some explanation?

Comment: It's a freakin' regex that extracts parts from a string... no mistery here.

Comment: how it can use for all condition like (<,>,>=,>=) ?>

Comment: Isn't it already working for all combinations of <,>,= ? Please provide a string example where it is not.